# Solutions for the differential equation $y'=|y|^\alpha$ with $y(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying for a final, for my first ODEs class, and I've stumbled upon this problem:

Given $\alpha > 0$ and the following ODE with initial values

$$\begin{cases}y'(t) = |y(t)|^{\alpha} \\ y(0) = 0\end{cases}$$

Determine for which $\alpha$ can we be sure that $y \equiv 0$ is the only solution to the equation, and for all the other possible values of $\alpha$, show an alternative solution.

I could not make any progress yet, and have tried for a considerable amount of time. If I'm not mistaken, we want to determine for which $\alpha$ is $|y|^{\alpha}$ Lipschitz; because in that case, Picard's theorem guarantees that $y \equiv 0$ is the only solution. I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $y'(t)\ge 0$

so $y$ is an increasing function and since $y(0)=0$ we know that $y(t)$ is the same sign as $t$.

So we can find explicit solutions because on the two intervals $]-\infty,0]$ and $[0,+\infty[$ the function $y$ is of constant sign and we can get rid of the absolute value in the equation.

Also we will suppose $y$ does not annulate elsewhere than in zero, which is equivalent to say that $y$ is strictly increasing, so we can integrate $y'/y^\alpha$.

Unfortunately $|y|^\alpha$ is Lipschitz only for $\alpha=1$ (for other values we have either a problem in $0$ either in $\infty$), so Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem can be applied only in this case.

About regularity, since we suppose $y$ differentiable then it is continuous, and then from equation $y'$ become continuous, so if a solution exists it is at least $C^1$.

For $t\ge 0,\ y(t)\ge 0\ :\quad  y'=y^\alpha$

- If $\alpha=1$ then $y=Ae^t,\ $ In zero we get $A=0$ so $y=0$.
- If $\alpha>1$ let's call $\beta=(\alpha-1)>0$ then $\displaystyle{\frac1{y^\beta}=-\beta(A+t)}$ and there is no solution because of divergence in zero.
- If $\alpha<1$ let's call $\beta=(1-\alpha)\in\;]0,1]$ then $\displaystyle{y^\beta=\beta(A+t)}$. In zero we get $A=0$ so $y(t)=(\beta t)^{\frac1\beta}$

For $t\le 0,\ y(t)\le 0\ :\quad  (-y')=-(-y)^\alpha$

- If $\alpha=1$ then $-y=Ae^{-t},\ $ In zero we get $A=0$ so $y=0$.
- If $\alpha>1$ let's call $\beta=(\alpha-1)>0$ then $\displaystyle{\frac1{(-y)^\beta}=-\beta(A-t)}$ and there is no solution because of divergence in zero.
- If $\alpha<1$ let's call $\beta=(1-\alpha)\in\;]0,1]$ then $\displaystyle{(-y)^\beta=\beta(A-t)}$. In zero we get $A=0$ so $-y(t)=(-\beta t)^{\frac1\beta}$

#### conclusion :

- For $\alpha=1$, the only solution is $y=0$ (unicity by Cauchy-Lipchitz).
- For $\alpha>1$, $y=0$ is solution and there are no solutions strictly increasing.
- For $0<\beta=(1-\alpha)<1$, there are two solutions $y=0\ \ $ and  $\ \ y(t)=\operatorname{sgn(t)}\times(\beta|t|)^{\frac1\beta}$

Since unicity is not asserted except in the first case, can we find piecewise $C^1$ solutions ?

The case $\alpha>1$ stays problematic, because $y(t)\to 0$ means $1/y^\beta\to\infty$ so it cannot be glued anywhere to $y=0$, the only other solution we know of that works in $t=0$.

For $\alpha<1$ we can glue $y=0$ on $[-\infty,t_0]$ to $y=(\beta(t-t_0))^{\frac1\beta}$ on $[t_0,+\infty]$ and this connection is $C^1$ in general since $1/\beta>1$ but it can be made $C^\infty$ for $\beta=\frac 1n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. For other values, there is a step, where the $n^{th}-$derivative of $y$ has a vertical tangent (because $\frac 1\beta-n<0$).

So for $\alpha<1$ we can find an infinity of maximal solutions and they are even $C^\infty$ for $\alpha=\frac{n-1}{n}$ with $n\in\mathbb N$.

There are other gluing of solutions that are working, I won't explicit them all, but you can try to find them :p

A last word to conclude, maybe there are also other hidden solutions, but since we do not have a theorem of unicity or tools to calculate them, we cannot do much more.

Comment: "$y$ does not annulate", what language is that from?  Around here we may say "$y$ does not vanish"

Comment: @GEdgar I am not the one who answered (I'm the OP) but in Spanish "vanish" is sometimes translated as *anular*. E.g.: "$f$ vanishes at $1$" may be translated as "$f$ se anula en $1$". The usual meaning of the word is that of "to make void, to cancel"; but in this case it is related with the expression *nulo* for something that is zero (c.f. *null* in English). Both expressions seem to come from latin; perhaps other romance languages have similar expressions.