# Uniqueness Theorem for a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Find all the solutions to the ODE initial value problem:
$$
x' = |x|^{1/3} $$ 
$$x(0)=0$$

Solution thus far:

Clearly, I must show it has a unique solution, hence Lipschitz continuity must hold. That is, we have:

$ \forall \; (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} , \exists L \in \mathbb{R} \; \text{such that}
\\
||x_1|^{1/3}-|x_2|^{1/3}| < L|x_1 - x_2| $

However, I am quite unsure the solution is unique at all, so I then must consider the weaker case of this theorem which is that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that the solution is unique on the interval $ \forall t \in (t_0 - \delta , t_0 + 
\delta) $ 
However I am unsure how to even use this or if it even helps me

Comment: The function on the right hand side is not Lipschitz at $x=0$. Your problem has more than one solution.

Comment: $x(t)=0$ is a solution, $x(t)=ct^{3/2}$ for $t>0$ or $x(t)=ct\sqrt{|t|}$ for all $t$ is a solution for some non-zero $c$, thus you do not get uniqueness.

Comment: Well, the problem is to find all solutions not uniqueness, which is why I stated the weaker theorem below where it is only unique on the interval I wrote above. Thanks for showing me counter examples of uniqueness, however, it still does not fully answer the question

Comment: let $ a > 0$ Define a function $x(t)$ as follows:  $ \frac{27}{8} (t-a)^{3/2} = x(t) \forall t \geq a \; \text{and} \; x(t)= 0 \forall t < a$

Comment: Does this not define an infinite family of functions? I'm so confused

Comment: you may be interested in a general discussion I studied some time ago. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173984/solutions-for-the-differential-equation-y-y-alpha-with-y0-0/2174083#2174083 Basically the fact that solutions must be $\nearrow$ help finding maximal solutions.

Comment: You can then also add on a negative branch $x(t)=-\frac{27}8(b-t)^{3/2}$ for $t<b$ where $b\le 0\le a$, with $x(t)=0$ for $b\le t \le a$ to get infinity squared in the amount of solutions.